# Float always return .00

Tags: c

When I input for example 10 and 4 it just return 2.00 instead of 2.50.

here is my function call in the main:

printf("\nQuotient = %.2f", quot(num1, num2));

Here is my user defined function that computes the quotient of two numbers x and y:

```
float quot(int x, int y){
    float quotient;
    if(x > y){
        quotient = x / y;
    }
    else{
        quotient = y / x;
    }
    return quotient;
}
```

Comment: the code seemed to be cut for some reason but that is the start below the function name

Comment: First division in integer 10/4 = 2, Then convert to float 2.0.

Comment: so thats why its returning .00 because the inputted numbers are integers? 5/2=2 which is 2.0 but if I were to input 5.0 / 2.0 its gonna be 2.5 ?

Comment: Cast the ints to floats and should work as expected: `quotient = (float)x / (float)y` and `quotient = (float)y / (float)x`